# Change the triangle shape next to TreeViewItem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, treeviewitem

How can I change the triangle shape next to the expandable `TreeViewItem` in the `XAML` below?

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem  Header="Columns" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Model" IsSelected="True"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Layout"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Elevations"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Beams/Floors" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Model"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Layout"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Elevations"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Foundation" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Model"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Layout"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Walls" IsExpanded="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Model"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Layout"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Elevations"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `TreeView`. You can see in the template the style `ExpandCollapseToggleStyle` in which there are two `Path` named `Collapsed` and `Expanded`. You can change them as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the mentioned link [Change Icon](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/adding-images-to-a-tree-view-in-wpf.aspx)